# Cocos2d Android adding CCsprite setpositon method lowering image quality?

Tags: android, background, cocos2d-android

I have a background.png image which is 4385x801 in pixel.The device that i add this image is 480x800.Now as you see width is greater than device in order to make rolling background.However when i add this sprite setting position according to screen with the code background.setPosition(CGPoint.make((s.width / 3)+80, s.height / 2)); image quality is not even near to real one.Why this change in quality appears?Do i need to use something so that no scaling will be made?Why do you think it happens and how can i prevent this?
[URL=https://imageshack.com/i/nr934tp][IMG]http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/640x480q90/855/934t.png[/IMG][/URL]

Comment: Dont use cocos2d-android lib ... it's almost dead. you will get less solution compair to the other SDK / game engine like : cocos2d-x / libgdx etc....

Comment: yes i see.thats why i will use libgdx instead